# Computing the Smith normal form $\begin{pmatrix} 1-x&2\\ 0&1-x \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck trying to compute the Smith normal form of the following

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1-x&2\\
0&1-x
\end{pmatrix}$$

I have

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1-x&2\\
0&1-x
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1-x&1+x\\
0&1-x
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1-x&1+x\\
0&2
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1-x&2\\
0&2
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1-x&0\\
0&2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
but $2$ does not divide $1-x$, can someone point out what I'm missing?

I have gotten other forms as well but none of them turned out to satisfy the divisibility requirement.

Comment: In which  PID are we supposed to work? ($\Bbb Z[X]$ is not principal).

Comment: And, to state the obvious, in $\mathbb Q[x]$, $2$ *does* divide $1-x$.  (The quotient is $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}x$.)

Comment: I'm asked to show that the matrix (A-xI) have the smith normal form of [[1,0],[0,(1-x)^2] where A=[[1,2],[0,1]] where A is in the ring Z

Comment: I think your calculation is adrift. You've got a string of $5$ matrices, and I don't believe the third is a legal transform of the second. I think the $0$ entry is wrong. (You can't change the degree of the determinant by legal moves.)

Comment: As others have said this does not make sense. If you work over $\mathbb{Q}$, though,  the Smith Normal Form is indeed diagonal with entries $1$ [the hcf of the entries] and $(1-x)^2$ [for correct determinant].